# Как закрывать меню после клика по ссылке?

Tags: javascript, html

Нужен способ закрыть меню, после клика по ссылке в меню. После перехода по ссылке и возврате в броузере назад - меню тоже остается открытым а хотелось бы чтобы после клика меню закрывалось.

```
<header>
<input type='checkbox' id='toggle' style='display:none;'/>
<label class='toggle-btn' for='toggle'>
<span class="bar"></span>
<span class="bar"></span>
</label>
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">link3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">link4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">link5</a></li>
<li>
<div class="container">
<a href="#">
<div id="ic1"></div></a>
<a href="#" target="_blank" style="display:block;">
<div id="ic2"></div></a>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
```